# A way to sit 2 Divs next to each other when 1st Div width is unknown?

Tags: css, html

this is my first post on this forum. I've used this forum a tone before to find out help and it's always been really helpful and useful. Straight forward help.

My problem I have is I want 2 divs to sit directly next to each other. I'm making a blog page for a community dance group. I have the div siting next to each other by utilising the float:left property in CSS. I found that solution on StackOverflow, thanks!!

But I don't know the width of Div 1, as I want it to sit in the middle of the page.

My CSS code:

```
.contentsWrapper{
margin-left:100px;
margin-right:100px;
margin-bottom:10px;
overflow:auto;
}
.blogWrapper{
float:left;
}
.archievesWrapper{
width:250px;
float:right;
}
```

Any help would be great!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be that's you want. Write like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="right">right</div>
<div class="left">left</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left{
    background:red;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:30px;
}
.right{
    float:right;
    background:green;
    height:30px;
    width:250px;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/6EufF/1/

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
display: inline-block
```

on both your divs.  That should get them to show next to eachother.

Comment: even if i dont know the width of the first div?

Comment: @ScottRobertson the browser does know the width of the first div. You should also accept the answers that work for you. And if they don't you should consider giving reasons for it, unless there is a better answer available.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to search for is "fluid layout".

There are different ways to do it. This kind of problematic have been addressed many times on different websites.

Here's one link to help you out, but you can find, many, many more.

http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/fluid-layout-code/